# Installable desktop application in java with desktop integration

Tags: java, deployment

I need some open source and cross platform framework/tool/library which provides functionalitites commonly available to native desktop applications, for example:

1. A user-friendly way to install the application
2. Finding out user's home directory
3. Finding out directory for persistent storage for files and configuration (can be different from home directory)
4. Finding out a suitable temporary directory for temporary storage of files
5. Starting a component in background when user logs in
6. Ability to open files with corresponding default programs

Does one exist?

Comment: Why not doing it for yourself, in Java?

Comment: You can use [izpack](http://izpack.org/) to create a custom installer.

Comment: Edited question to make it more clear what I need

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have used [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) sometimes back. It's pretty good.